# Algorithm for BFS traveral of an acylic directed graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, dependencies, traversal

I'm looking for an elegant Python program that does a BFS traveral of a DAG:

Node A is connected to B (`A->B`) if A "depends on" B (think of python package Foo "depending upon" Bar: Foo->Bar).

In a graph of about 7000 such nodes, I want to sort all nodes such that for all possible `(i, j)` where `1>=i<j<=7000` .. `depends(Ni, Nj)` is False. depends(A, B) = True if and only if `A->B` or A "depends on" B .. and `Nx` is the node occuring in `x`th position in the sorted list.

Note: A node can have multiple parents. Eg: A->C and B->C. Therefore, according to the above sorting rule, A and B must come before C.

Comment: Mind clearing up that last paragraph?

Comment: @LFSR - I've tried to think of the BFS tree traversal I know, but then it would not be applicable to graphs/forests .. where a node can have multiple parents.

Comment: I believe he wants topological sort.

Comment: @niteria - wow, that's it .. how come I forgot topological sort (despite studying algorithms at school and parcitiparing in the ACM ICPC regionals). guess, I am getting old..

Comment: @pianoman: I edited it a bit. Does that clarify it for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am reading the question correctly, it looks like you want a [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting).  The most efficient algorithm (O(V+E)) for doing this was proposed by [Tarjan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Tarjan), and a Python implementation can be found [here](http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html).

Off-topic, but it seems as though your package dependency analogy is reversed; I would think that "A depends on B" would imply "B->A", but of course this will not change the structure of the tree, merely reverse it.